# Python Scikit-learn MultiOutput Regression - enforce floor limit when predicting numerical values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a very simple program below that builds a model using multi-output regression. Even though all the training data consists of positive float values I'm discovering that predictions made often yield negative values. How can I tell scikit to enforce a floor of 0 (or in other words not make negative predictions)?

```
import csv
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = []
Y = []

results = []
with open("folder/training_data.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:  # each row is a list
        x = row[:5]
        y = row[5:]
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.15)

gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor()
model = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=gbr)

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain)

...


prediction = model.predict([[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]])

# I get e.g. [[-0.2, -0.1]] back where I'd rather have [[0,0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `MultiOutputRegressor`. It rather is the `GradientBoostingRegressor`.

Regressors in general might yield some weird outputs beyond the range of `y` values. Yet, if your `xtest` and `ytest` don't contain negative values nor are far a way from the training set distribution (*i.e. **quite arbitrary** or in other words, not coming from the same training set distribution, which is just in theory, as a one probable cause*), it's very unlikely to have those negative values with most of the regressors, except our buddy the `GradientBoostingRegressor`!.

Probably, the issue is happening because of how `GradientBoostingRegressor` works. If you read about it, you find:

> GB builds an additive model in a forward stage-wise fashion; it allows
> for the optimization of arbitrary differentiable loss functions. In
> each stage a regression tree is fit on the negative gradient of the
> given loss function.

That means each stage fits regression trees to the prior stage residuals, now if the error for a given sample is big (i.e the loss is big), it will yield a negative value for that stage. Hence, it is not impossible for the algorithm to end up with a negative output when it sums up the values of all trees.

You can attempt to solve this by trying to improve your model, such as decreasing `n_estimators`, or trying different loss function..etc.

You can read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.fit) for the full list of parameters.

Finally, you might also want to consider using [`GridSearchCV` along with `MultiOutputRegressor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532811/gridsearch-over-multioutputregressor), which might help.

---

**P.S**: If the vector `[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]` that you used is quite different from your training data (i.e. **quite arbitrary**), then the prediction might be very legitimate as per I explained above. In fact, other regerssors might output weird prediction in response to what they consider "weird inputs"!. If the latter is particularly the case, then there's nothing really to do more than wrapping the prediction function with another function that makes negative values --> zeros, something like this (do the required checks and tweaks, if required):

```
def predict(model, sample):
    res = model.predict(sample)
    return res[res < 0] = 0
```

Comment: >> `nor are far a way from the training set` How do you know that? Why not consider extrapolating out of training region as a primary reason?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Read my update, I meant by that "**quite arbitrary**". Since test set is expected to be drawn from the same satistical distribution of the train set. This is a theoretical discussion, and not implying that the OP should make sure of that practically (though there are some measure to see how far two distributions are far from each other).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation on the cause

Answer (score 0):

If your training target is always higher than 0 you can try with a tweedie loss or a poisson loss.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_tweedie_deviance.html

I am not aware if GBM supports this 2 but XGBoost and HistBoost do:

1. https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html#parameters-for-tweedie-regression-objective-reg-tweedie
2. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor.html:

> “poisson” losses actually implement “half least squares loss” and “half poisson deviance” to simplify the computation of the gradient. Furthermore, “poisson” loss internally uses a log-link and requires y >= 0.

BR
/Edgar