# Does anybody know Hyperparameters of GridSearchCV for MultiOutputClassifier model?

Tags: python, pandas, gridsearchcv

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

*parameters = {**?????**}*

search = GridSearchCV(_pipeline,  n_jobs=1, cv= 5, param_grid=parameters)

#multi_target_linear = MultiOutputClassifier(search)



search.fit(X, y)

#search.get_params().keys()


search.best_params_
```

Answer (score 0):

***Hyperparameters*** in a case like this would vary from case to case, as they are what you want to solve for, arriving at hyperparameters that are both accurate and efficient.

From what it seems, you aim to create a parameter grid called `parameters`, that includes several hyperparameters that you want to hone down on.  GridSearchCV can then try all the combinations of hyperparameters and find the best performing combination.  The CV is Cross Validation, which is a way of shuffling the training and test sets for fair evaluation, which you here have 5 different segments, hence `cv=5`.

You also are using [MultiOutputClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html), which is designed to adapt other classifiers to be able to handle multiple targets, but you don't define what classifier that is.

Comment: I am sorry, this  should be helpful:                   
       '''X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=36, random_state=0) _pipeline = Pipeline([ ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()).fit(X, y)) ]) for category in categories: y_pred = _pipeline.predict(X)'''

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `param_grid` of [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) is determined by its `estimator`, but you didn't write how `_pipeline` is constructed.
So I cannot answer this question, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43533071/9965922) will help.

Comment: I am sorry guys, let me show you a structure:                                                                             '''X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=36, random_state=0)
_pipeline = Pipeline([
               ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()).fit(X, y))
            ])

for category in categories:    
    y_pred = _pipeline.predict(X)'''

Comment: @EgorPetrov You are using 'Pipeline' in wrong way. See the link in my answer.

Comment: I changed MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()) to MultiOutputClassifier(SVR) and used paramets as for SVR and my pipeline works now. I do not know why it did not work for KneighborClassifier or I did not have parameters for this.